iframe loaded has correct src but not downloading the pdf
I have an angular v17 application , also I have a button which when being clicked will fire below function and  I have a url to a pdf which url in browser loads the pdf normally and its fine , but I want to start downloading on the same page not opening another url by <a/> anchor by clicking on the button using an iframe and then removing it from the document body but its not working , when I click on the button nothing happens , anyone please can help whats the problem ? and how to fix it ?
 downloadInvoice(url: string): void {
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = 'iframe-download';
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  iframe.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.onload = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementById('iframe-download'));
  };
}

}

I mean sth like this document.body.removeChild(iframe) by  the statememt "then removing it from the document body"

its just for downloading by creating a iframe containing a src it will load the iframe and by loading it should start downloading (which does not in my case as it has bug) after finishing the download the iframe should be removed as by refreshing the page any time we will have a new iframe and by loading it will start download

This question is very unclear, are you wanting the PDF to replace the page in the current tab, display as content in the current page, or just download it to the local filesystem?

If your goal is just to give the user a button to click and then download the PDF, the most common method is using an hyperlink (tag: a).
Here is an example:
downloadInvoice(url: string): void {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    const downloader = document.createElement("a");
    downloader.href = url;
    downloader.download = "invoice.pdf";
    downloader.click();
    downloader.remove();
  }
}

Thus, when the user clicks the button that invokes this function, the browser will open the save dialog for them to save the invoice.pdf."

Hey , Thanks for your reply , No I had this and changed to iframe , I want. to be downloaded in the page actually

In this case, 'downloaded in the page actually' would mean displaying the content in an iframe on the page?

no there is a way that it starts download in the page not opening another tab
